# bash check if a given file exists in a directory is failing on wildcard

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
FILE=*.tf
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
> echo "$FILE exists."
> else
> echo "$FILE does not exist."
> fi
does not exist.
```

The directory Im running this in has a file `myfile.tf` in it.

Im wondering why this isnt finding the `myfile.tf` file - could it be because im using the `*` asterisk wildcard ? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Pathname expansion is not performed on variable assignment statements or double-quoted strings. `FILE=*.tf; [ -f "$FILE" ]` will return 1 unless there is a file named `*.tf` in the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard will give you a list.

Using `bash`:

```
exist_files() {
  ext="${1}"
  for file in *."${ext}"; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && return 0
  done
  return 1
}

if exist_files "tf"; then
  echo "File matching *.tf exists"
else
  echo "File matching *.tf doesn't exists"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you put this in if/else form? Thanks so much

Comment: `Can you put this in if/else form?` `if at_least_one_file=0; for file in *.tf; do [[ -f file ]] && at_least_one_file=1; done; [[ $at_least_one_file -lt 1 ]]; then .... fi`

Comment: `[[ $(exist_files "tf") == "yes" ]]` ugh, that's horrible. Instead: `exist_files() {  ... return 0; ... return 1; }`and just `if exist_files "tf"; then ... fi`

Comment: @Jshee I've updated my answer to make a more friendly function that you can use in an if/else statement (and which is a little bit more optimized because it stop the loop when it find the first occurence that match)

Comment: @KamilCuk I agree in this simple case ^^ (I've updated my answer before reading your comments) but sometimes I prefer to make it a clear difference between `$?` as a potential error/exception to handle and a string or boolean result of my functions (`return 1` != `return true` but more like a `throw new SomeException()`).

Comment: In such cases, you have 255 numbers to choose from. It's a convention typical - `[` returns 0 on true, `1` on false and 2 on error.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes I understand, it's a problem of confidence because I'm used to use programs which don't always follow those conventions (puppet for example). So I'm a little paranoid. And sometimes it can be felt even in simple problems. I know that is not a good thing (so it's for this reason I've updated my answer :p ).

Comment: Question for OP @IdrissNeumann - does this recurse into subdirs?

Comment: @Jshee nope but in that case, `find` is your friend :)